# Solving a complex valued functional equation

Tags: functional-equations

I have an equation in the following form:

$\frac{1}{r}F(s-j) = F(s) - F^{2}(s)$

Where $r$ is a real valued constant, $j$ is the unit imaginary number, $s$ is a complex variable and $F$ is a complex function. Any idea how to approach this?

Comment: $F^2$ is composition? Or Squaring?

Comment: It's squaring..